Vec clears, when I use rust workspaces with my crate
I have recently created a tool, that allows me to access struct from anywhere in the code, just by the structs name.
The way it works is pretty simple, allocate enough space to hold the desired structs, and store a pointer to each, and access them, by dereferencing.
#[derive(Debug, Default, Module)]
pub struct SomeStruct {
    test_u8: u8,
    test_vec: Vec<u8>,
}

#[derive(Debug, Default, Module)]
pub struct OtherStruct {
    pub test_vec: Vec<u8>,
}


fn main() {
    let bundle = ModuleBundleBuilder::default()
        .add_module::<SomeStruct>()
        .add_module::<OtherStruct>()
        .build()
        .unwrap();

    module_manager::init(bundle);

    let other_struct = get_module_mut::<OtherStruct>();
    other_struct.test_vec = Vec::new();
    other_struct.test_vec.push(2);
    other_struct.test_u8 = 2;

    dbg!(&other_struct.test_vec.as_ptr());
    //[app/src/main.rs:25:5] &other_struct.test_vec.as_ptr() = 0x000058ff06362c50
    get_module_mut::<SomeStruct>().test_vec = Vec::new();
    dbg!(&other_struct.test_vec.as_ptr());
    //[app/src/main.rs:27:5] &other_struct.test_vec.as_ptr() = 0x0000000000000001
    dbg!(&other_struct.test_u8);
    //[app/src/main.rs:30:5] &other_struct.test_u8 = 2
}

The above example, works perfectly fine, when I use it in a single package. The problem occurs I when I start using workspaces and define either struct in a different member of the workspace.
As in the example, when I have two structs, each holding a Vec, when I mutate either, the other gets dropped or cleared.
At this point, I do not have any ideas on how could I solve the problem, hope it is not a limitation or bug of rust itself. The tool is on crates.io, called module manager.
I would be real happy if somebody could suggest me a solution.

What is Module, ModuleBundleBuilder, …? Please add a [mre] (i.e. include imports).

@cafce25 As mentioned in the question, these structs come from https://docs.rs/module_manager/0.2.3/module_manager/. Otherwise agreed – the problematic code itself should be included in the question, with a minimal example exposing the problem.

For what it's worth, It looks like you could trivially implement your library in safe Rust using a HashMap<TypeId, Box<dyn Any>>. Retrieving an instance of type T would be something like my_map.get(&TypeId::of::<T>())?.downcast_ref().unwrap(). (The unwrap() should be fine if you guarantee that if there is a value for the given type id it has the right type.)

This smells like UB.

Is this library (module_manager) yours?

This library you're using (module_manager) is full of UB and unsoundness. Don't use it.
You can achieve what you want with the following simple and safe code:
use std::any::{Any, TypeId};
use std::cell::{Ref, RefCell, RefMut};
use std::collections::HashMap;

pub struct ModuleBundle {
    map: HashMap<TypeId, RefCell<Box<dyn Any>>>,
}

impl ModuleBundle {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            map: HashMap::new(),
        }
    }

    pub fn add_module<M: Any>(&mut self, module: M) {
        self.map
            .insert(TypeId::of::<M>(), RefCell::new(Box::new(module)));
    }

    pub fn get_module<M: Any>(&self) -> Option<Ref<'_, M>> {
        self.map.get(&TypeId::of::<M>()).map(|module| {
            Ref::map(module.borrow(), |module| {
                module.downcast_ref::<M>().unwrap()
            })
        })
    }

    pub fn get_module_mut<M: Any>(&self) -> Option<RefMut<'_, M>> {
        self.map.get(&TypeId::of::<M>()).map(|module| {
            RefMut::map(module.borrow_mut(), |module| {
                module.downcast_mut::<M>().unwrap()
            })
        })
    }
}

This does not allow you to get a module mutably twice, as required by Rust's laws.

I was just experimenting with an idea. But to improve myself, what part of my code results in undefined behavior? As I understand, as far as I can keep track of my pointers, and know exacly, what I am accessing, when dereferencing it, shouldn't be ub. But I am open to any suggestions

@PappAdam A lot. Unsafe code is hard to write. Non-exhaustive list: no synchronization on setting the global modules, allowing you to get two mutable references to the same module, no handling of alignment...

And all the references that are returned are 'static, while the underlying data isn't.
